# Add a comma with Javascript or CSS to WordPress Shortcode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently using the following theme - http://3clicks.bringthepixel.com/shortcodes/other/number/

They have a number generating shortcode... If I place the number 1000 into the shortcode I get 1000, without the comma. I'd like to add one so I checked the code with firebug.

I see there's a span class - `<span class="g1-thousands-separator"></span>`

You can view an example of a thousand marker here - http://3clicks.bringthepixel.com/home/home-3/

For some reason I can't add anything with a CSS code... and when I place a "," into the number it doesn't appear. How can I go about adding a comma to separate a thousand and million mark?

thank you

Comment: Why don't you edit your theme files?

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
.g1-thousands-separator:after {
    content: ',';
}
```

Comment: That worked! I never even knew about the content property. Does this work on all browsers?

Comment: I would say so... Browser support on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Comment: @user2752620 If my answer solved your problem (and it seems that it did), could you please accept my answer?